# regex work in all .net engine online but not in powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I tested this regex below in regexstorm (.NET engine) and it worked, but in PowerShell (v2) it doesn't work...why ?

```powershell
$str = 'powershell is rock powershell is not rock'
$re = [regex]'@
 (?xmin)
  ^
  (
   (?> [^i]+ | \Bi | i(?!s\b) )*
   \bis\b
  ){2}
   (?> [^i]+ | \Bi | i(?!s\b) )*$
'@
$re.matches($str)
# not return value why ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 2 Problems

#### 1. A typo:

```powershell
$re = [regex]'@
...
'@
```

should be

```powershell
$re = [regex]@'
...
'@
```

#### 2. Whitespace

When you use a here string like that, the whitespace at the beginning of the lines counts! You're making it part of the expression. Try this:

```powershell
$str = 'powershell is rock powershell is not rock'
$re = [regex]@'
(?xmin)
^
(
(?> [^i]+ | \Bi | i(?!s\b) )*
\bis\b
){2}
(?> [^i]+ | \Bi | i(?!s\b) )*$
'@
$re.matches($str)
# not return value why ?
```

### Post Edit

After reading your comment, it seems like you're trying to match a string that contains 2 instances of the word `is` (no more no less).

I recommend doing this with more code and less regex:

```powershell
$s1 = 'powershell is rock powershell is not rock'
$s2 = 'powershell is what powershell is vegetable is not'
$s3 = 'powershell is cool'

$re = [regex]'\bis\b'

$re.matches($s1).captures.count
$re.matches($s2).captures.count
$re.matches($s3).captures.count
```

A much simpler regex, and you can simply test if `$re.matches($str).captures.count -eq 2` (or `-ne 2`).

Comment: Well, your regex looks a bit weird. I'm not really sure what it is you're trying to match. Could you edit your question to elaborate on what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: The pattern validate a string it only match all string if the word  'is' is repeted only 2 time.

Comment: Thank this work like a charm...but why my pattern work in all engine but not in powershell..you can try with regexstorm or any other regex engine...it' bug ?

Comment: I don't for sure, and I can't test it now, but it may be a whitespace issue. Not just the whitepsace at the beginning of the lines, but the spaces between characters. Remember that a space in a regex matches a literal space. Perhaps the online engines, since they're HTML based, are collapsing or eliminating whitespace?

Comment: No, The 'x' modifier trim all space in pattern..its not a space problem

Comment: Ah, I see that now, I missed it before.